GnuTLS error signal 4 on QEMU/KVM with cpu set to "host-model"
In order to be able to script VM generation on our Debian 11 QEMU/KVM hosts I wrote a little python script which uses virt-install to setup new virtual machines (with OS Ubuntu 22.04). In those VMs created programmatically, however, I was not able to use Git on HTTPS repos without explicit GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1; I always received error: git-remote-https died of signal 4 (also other commands which involved GNUTLS
In manually created VMs I could successfully clone, however, so I started comparing the respective settings and was finally able to find the problem: it is the concrete CPU mode. Working VMs (manually created via virt-manager) use host-passthrough, while those VMs that are created using my script (and thus virt-install) use host-model (which yields EPYC ROME while running).

Apparently there is a difference in the default values virt-manager and virt-install use - is that true?

I assume that GNUTLS erroneously assumes a specific CPU feature to be available and then tries to use it which leads to a segfault or similar. Is the CPU feature detection of QEMU flawed for my "EPYC ROME" CPUs?


Thanks in advance!

Compare the cpuid tool's output from host and guest?
